# CentOS7 postfix install, selinux blocks cleanup

Tags: postfix, selinux

I installed postfix successfully and when I start it as root/sudo with-

```
postfix start
```

...it runs unconfined and sends emails.

When I set it to automatically start at boot with-

```
systemctl enable postfix.service
```

...it starts up at boot time and runs fine but sending emails is blocked by selinux.

When sending an email, the log shows-

```
Jun  6 11:12:20 mainbox kernel: [ 1045.572306] type=1400 audit(1496761940.747:254): avc:  denied  { read write } for  pid=970 comm="cleanup" name="unix.cleanup" dev="xvda1" ino=131013 scontext=system_u:system_r:postfix_cleanup_t:s0 tcontext=unconfined_u:object_r:var_run_t:s0 tclass=file
Jun  6 11:12:20 mainbox kernel: [ 1045.592045] type=1300 audit(1496761940.747:254): arch=c000003e syscall=2 success=no exit=-13 a0=7f3eae371020 a1=2 a2=0 a3=3 items=0 ppid=811 pid=970 auid=4294967295 uid=0 gid=0 euid=0 suid=0 fsuid=0 egid=0 sgid=0 fsgid=0 tty=(none) ses=4294967295 comm="cleanup" exe="/usr/libexec/postfix/cleanup" subj=system_u:system_r:postfix_cleanup_t:s0 key=(null)
Jun  6 11:12:20 mainbox kernel: type=1400 audit(1496761940.747:254): avc:  denied  { read write } for  pid=970 comm="cleanup" name="unix.cleanup" dev="xvda1" ino=131013 scontext=system_u:system_r:postfix_cleanup_t:s0 tcontext=unconfined_u:object_r:var_run_t:s0 tclass=file
Jun  6 11:12:20 mainbox kernel: type=1300 audit(1496761940.747:254): arch=c000003e syscall=2 success=no exit=-13 a0=7f3eae371020 a1=2 a2=0 a3=3 items=0 ppid=811 pid=970 auid=4294967295 uid=0 gid=0 euid=0 suid=0 fsuid=0 egid=0 sgid=0 fsgid=0 tty=(none) ses=4294967295 comm="cleanup" exe="/usr/libexec/postfix/cleanup" subj=system_u:system_r:postfix_cleanup_t:s0 key=(null)
Jun  6 11:12:20 mainbox postfix/cleanup[970]: fatal: open lock file pid/unix.cleanup: cannot open file: Permission denied
Jun  6 11:12:21 mainbox postfix/master[811]: warning: process /usr/libexec/postfix/cleanup pid 970 exit status 1
Jun  6 11:12:21 mainbox postfix/master[811]: warning: /usr/libexec/postfix/cleanup: bad command startup -- throttling
```

So I used a2a to try and fix it but I get a warning that the new rule is too permissive-

```
grep 'postfix_cleanup_t' /var/log/audit/audit.log | audit2allow -m postfix_cleanup > postfix_cleanup.te
cat postfix_cleanup.te
```

Produces-

```
module postfix_cleanup 1.0;

require {
    type var_run_t;
    type postfix_cleanup_t;
    class file { read write };
}

#============= postfix_cleanup_t ==============

#!!!! WARNING: 'var_run_t' is a base type.
allow postfix_cleanup_t var_run_t:file { read write };
```

...allowing postfix to run all over a base type is too permissive.

How to correctly fix this?

Comment: Fixed: relabeling the filesystem `(restorecon -RF /)` was all that was needed. Wish I'd thought of that sooner. ;)

Answer (score 0):

**Specific files in postfix missing context**

There are a few [bugs](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=960894) around this.  Is your selinux policy fully updated?

**Files losing context**

If files are losing context, that is likely due to the `restorecond` service not running and files being moved around.

Comment: Thanks- yes, looked at that. But it did need to be relabeled.

Comment: To get into that state usually requires that `restorecond` is not running and something moved files around.